# Conditional formatting using dates

Tags: excel, date, conditional-formatting

I have data like this:

In one sheet I have a `table A` with dates (ascending order) and account balances.
In another `table B`, I want to retrieve the balance on the last day of the month.

Now, I want to set the font color to white if the the latest date in `table A` is smaller than the corresponding date in `table B`.

See screenshot below, I want the marked area to be white (June 2014 and later). I think this can be done with conditional formatting.

Someone knows?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting in A19, select the cells in the row. Create a new conditional format based on a formula

```
=DATE(YEAR(A16),MONTH(A16),1)>MAX($C$1:$C$13)
```

Format the text white for this rule.

[image]